# uploaded video not showing up

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So I have uploaded videos for a `class` model for an educational website but that video is not being rendered. What can I do to render it?

My models.py:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='class/class_videos',null=True,
validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['MOV','avi','mp4','webm','mkv'])])


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='class/instructor_pics', null=True)
    instructor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    instructor_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='class/instructor_pics', null=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='courses_joined', blank=True)
    classes = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My views.py:

```
class CourseDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'class/course.html'
```

My html file :

```
{% extends "class/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
  {{ object.classes.video }}
{% endblock content %}
```

The output is the title of the class and the `<name>.mp4` filename where name is the name of the video file I uploaded. But I want the video to be rendered. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `object.classes.video.url`: `<video controls width="250"> <source src="{{ object.classes.video.url }}" type="video/mp4">
Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>`

Comment: The [**<video>**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) HTML element embeds a media player which supports video playback into the document.